# Login in android with webservice using json

Tags: android, json, web-services, authentication

```
    package com.example.friendfinder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    String APIurl = "http://friendfinder.hostzi.com/ws/";
    Button btnlogin;
    TextView login_user;
    TextView login_pass;
    TextView tv;
    JSONObject jObject;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog alert;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        start();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_entrar:
            if (checkStatus()) {
                progressDialog.show();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            jObject = new JSONObject(getJSON("login.php?email="
                                    + login_user.getText().toString()
                                    + "&password="
                                    + login_pass.getText().toString()));
                            tv.setText(jObject.toString());
                            Log.e("JSON", jObject.toString());
                            if (jObject.getString("success").equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    "true")) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                confirm();
                            } else if (jObject.getString("success")
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                                login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        builder.setMessage("O inicio de sessão falhou, verifica os teus dados.");
                                        alert = builder.create();
                                        alert.show();
                                    }

                                });
                                login.this.runOnUiThread(null);

                            } else {
                                login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        builder.setMessage("O inicio de sessão falhou, verifica os teus dados.");
                                        alert = builder.create();
                                        alert.show();
                                    }

                                });
                                login.this.runOnUiThread(null);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
            }
            else{
                builder.setMessage("Não existe de momento nenhuma conexão à Internet! O ínicio de sessão é impossivel de realizar");
                alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        login_user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_user);
        login_pass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_pass);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_entrar);
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("A iniciar sessão...");
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    public void confirm(){
        Intent i = new Intent(login.this, maps.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

    public String getJSON(String rurl) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(APIurl + rurl);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public boolean checkStatus() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**LogCat**
http://pastebin.com/0xVv2pBR

When i click the button to login the app crashes and i realy can't understand what is wrong, if you need more information just ask me. If you know how to resolve help me please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logs says

> "02-06 18:50:47.785: I/Choreographer(874): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

if you are new to Android you must learn to implement [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in your `Activity`. You are not suppose to use webservice or http communication in `main/UI` `thread`. here i found [Tutorial to implement AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) please learn it will solve your problem.